# could not find array type for data type character varying[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have three tables (schema below). I want to select all users and display their distinct tags / count of distinct tags in a 2d array, like

```
1 | ['javascript':3]
2 | ['javascript':3, 'windows':2, 'osx':17]
...
```

After reviewing other questions on stackoverflow, I have:

```
select "Users".id, array_agg(array[q."TagName"::varchar[], q."TagCount"]::varchar[])
FROM "Users" 
LEFT JOIN (select "UserTags"."UserId" as "UserId", "Tags".name as "TagName", count("Tags".name)::varchar as "TagCount"
from "UserTags" 
LEFT JOIN "Tags" ON ("UserTags"."TagId" = "Tags".id)
GROUP BY "UserTags"."UserId", "Tags".id
 ) as q ON ("Users".id = "q"."UserId")
 group by "Users".id
```

and get an error:
`could not find array type for data type character varying[]`

How could I modify the above query to solve this?

----***Schema***----

**Tags**:

```
CREATE TABLE "Tags" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"Tags_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(255),
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Tags_pkey" ON "Tags"(id int4_ops);
```

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"Users_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    "firstName" character varying(255),
    "lastName" character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    manager boolean,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "AgencyId" character varying(255),
    "slackId" character varying(255),
    profile json,
    channel character varying(255),
    "scorecardCode" character varying(255),
    "imageUrl" character varying(255),
    "userName" character varying(255)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Users_pkey" ON "Users"(id int4_ops);
```

**UserTags** FK UserId = Users.id, TagId = Tags.id

```
CREATE TABLE "UserTags" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"UserTags_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    "UserId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Users"(id),
    "TagId" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "Tags"(id),
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "UserTags_pkey" ON "UserTags"(id int4_ops);
```

Comment: Do not post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text** (no images!) into your post.

Comment: i've added create statements and removed images

Comment: `q."TagName"::varchar[]` should be `q."TagName"`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried recreate tables without quotes?
I tried replicate your scenario and got a good result, i guess.

See:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tags_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE Tags (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(255),
    createdAt timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updatedAt timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
        
CREATE SEQUENCE Users_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE Users (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('Users_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName character varying(255),
    lastName character varying(255),
    email character varying(255),
    manager boolean,
    createdAt timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updatedAt timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    AgencyId character varying(255),
    slackId character varying(255),
    profile json,
    channel character varying(255),
    scorecardCode character varying(255),
    imageUrl character varying(255),
    userName character varying(255)
);
 
CREATE SEQUENCE UserTags_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE UserTags (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('UserTags_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(id),
    TagId integer NOT NULL REFERENCES Tags(id),
    createdAt timestamp with time zone,
    updatedAt timestamp with time zone
);    


INSERT INTO USERS (firstname, createdat , updatedat )
VALUES ('john doe',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO USERS (firstname, createdat , updatedat )
VALUES ('jane doe',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
    
INSERT INTO TAGS (name, createdat , updatedat )
VALUES ('javascript', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO TAGS (name, createdat , updatedat ) 
VALUES ('osx', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO TAGS (name, createdat , updatedat ) 
VALUES ('windows', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
     
INSERT INTO usertags(userid, tagid, createdat, updatedat)
VALUES (1,1,current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO usertags(userid, tagid, createdat, updatedat) 
VALUES (1,2,current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO usertags(userid, tagid, createdat, updatedat)
VALUES (2,2,current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO usertags(userid, tagid, createdat, updatedat)
VALUES (2,3,current_timestamp,current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO usertags(userid, tagid, createdat, updatedat)
VALUES (2,3,current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
```

I changed the query a little bit:

```
select Users.id
    , ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[q.TagName, q.TagCount])
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN
(
    select UserTags.UserId as UserId,  
    Tags.name as TagName, count(Tags.name)::varchar as TagCount
    from UserTags 
    LEFT JOIN Tags ON (UserTags.TagId = Tags.id)
    GROUP BY UserTags.UserId, Tags.id
) as q ON (Users.id = q.UserId)
group by Users.id;
```

And got this results:

```
1 | {{javascript,1},{osx,1}} 
2 | {{osx,1},{windows,2}}
```

Tell me if works for you.